# Associations Fetch Customization: Retrieving Category-Linked Posts and Orphan Posts

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I have a `Category` model that has a `one-to-many` relationship with a `Post` model:

```java
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I'm looking to fetch the `posts` associated with certain categories, but I want to customize the fetch behavior. Specifically, I want to retrieve both the `posts` linked to a specific category and the "orphan" `posts` that have no associated category (i.e., where `category` is `null`).

I'm seeking an advanced solution that can achieve this, potentially utilizing Hibernate features like `@Filter` or `@NamedEntityGraph`. While I'm aware of the option to use separate queries and merge the results, I'm looking for a more sophisticated approach.

Here's a conceptual idea that I have in mind, although I understand it may not be directly practical:

```java
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Sql("OR WHERE post.category IS NULL")
    private List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();
```

how to achieve this advanced customization of the fetch behavior for the posts associated with certain categories, including both category-linked posts and orphan posts?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would specifically want an 'advanced' solution (whatever that means), but you can fetch posts with and without a category using one query, without the need of merging results from multiple queries. Just use `WHERE p.category = :category OR p.category IS NULL`

Comment: Unfortunately, i need to get them from the category side `category.getPosts();` not directly run a query for them

Comment: Nope, you don't *need* to get them from the category side, you *want* to get them from the category side, which is a major difference. You're trying to make the framework do what it does not support and never promised to do.